# Question about a Mortarboard badge?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, badges

I achieved 200+ yesterday but this included assoc.. does it count towards Mortarboard?

I hoped it would have I worked my butt off trying to answer questions ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Mortarboard you need 200 reputation from votes alone.

> #### Mortarboard
>
> - bronze; awarded once; same family as Epic (silver), Legendary (gold)
> - Earned more than 200 reputation from vote types in a single day
>
>   - For the purposes of this badge, "vote types" include:
>
>     - upvotes on your questions
>     - upvotes on your answers
>     - acceptances of your answers
>     - bounties being awarded to your answers
>   - Reputation points earned for associating accounts or for accepting other users' answers to your own questions do **not** count for the
>       badge.
>   - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are **not** counted in local time
> - Sources: [Is 150 "rep cap exceeded" *alone* enough for Legendary badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge),
>     which includes [the actual query that produces the
>     badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge/58192#58192)
>     in an answer by Jeff, [How is it possible to exceed the rep cap
>     without reaching
>     it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it/49405#49405),
>     which features more human-readable comments by Jeff and
>     [Why don't I have the 'Mortarboard' badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100512/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge).
>     Reputation points earned for associating accounts or for accepting
>     other users' answers to your own questions do not count for the badge.

A description of all badges can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258).

Comment: ahh sucky :( can i get smiley face on my forehead atleast?

Comment: At least there's no `dunce` badge.

Comment: Ahhhh ahahah cheeeky :-)

Comment: Nice try.... :)